# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid columnmergedata <- merge (dataset1, dataset2, by.x="personalid")

Tags: r

```
mergedata <- merge (dataset1, dataset2, by.x="personalid")
```

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: please help this out as iam getting error

Comment: Do you have the same column names?

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example, it would be great.  For me, the code works fine

Answer (score 5):

The OP had specified only the `by.x`.  If the column names are the same, then `by` can be used

```
merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="personalid")
```

If the `by` variable names are different, then we need to specify the `by.y` as well

```
merge(dataset1, dataset2, by.x="personalid", by.y = "somethingelse")
```

Comment: its still showing a error

Comment: @charankumar  if you are not intending to show a small reproducible, it is difficult for others to know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: dataset1 <- read.csv("Census Income Data Set1.csv")
dataset2 <- read.csv("Census Income Data Set2.csv")
str(dataset1)
str(dataset2)
colnames(dataset1)[1] <- "personalid"
colnames(dataset2)[1] <- "perosnalid"merge(dataset1, dataset2, by.x="personalid", by.y = "somethingelse")

Comment: this is the full program

Comment: @charankumar  Your code, shows both the datasets have the same 'personalid', then why not use the `by = 'personalid'

Comment: dataset1 <- read.csv("Census Income Data Set1.csv")
dataset2 <- read.csv("Census Income Data Set2.csv")
str(dataset1)
str(dataset2)
colnames(dataset1)[1] <- "personalid"
colnames(dataset2)[1] <- "perosnalid"
merge(dataset1, dataset2, by="personalid")

Comment: @charankumar  what is the new error?  What does the `str` shows?

Comment: str shows thats its a  correct one but coming to merge cell it shows an error

Comment: @charankumar  Can you update your post with `str` and also `dput` of a small dataset

Comment: str(dataset2)
'data.frame': 48842 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ perosnalid    : Factor w/ 48842 levels "P1","P10","P100",..: 1 11112 22223 33334 43288 44399 45510 46621 47732 2 ...
 $ capital.gain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ capital.loss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hours.per.week: int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ native.country: Factor w/ 42 levels " Cambodia"," Canada",..: 39 39 39 39 5 39 23 39 39 39 ...
 $ class         : Factor w/ 2 levels " <=50K"," >50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...

Comment: @charankumar  There is an edit button where you can edit in your post

Comment: @charankumar ; can you add the results of `str` to your question (by clicking the *edit* button, bottom left of your question)  as it is difficult to see what is going on when added as comments. Akrun's answer should work.

Comment: huh, [from your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954874/error-in-fix-byby-x-x-by-must-specify-a-uniquely-valid-columnmergedata#comment86926380_49954891) above the variable is `perosnalid` not `personalid` - make sure of your spelling