# Error in fix.by (by.x, x): 'by' must define one or more columns as numbers, names or logical data

Tags: r, merge, na

I have some files

```
file_analysis = read.xlsx(listfiles[1],sheetIndex = 1,header = FALSE)###
#View(file_analysis)
str(file_analysis)
file_comments =  read.csv("C:/Users/adm/Downloads/comments.csv",sep=";")
#View(file_comments)
file_groups = read.xlsx(listfiles[6],sheetIndex = 1,header = FALSE)  ####
#View(file_groups)
file_headeers = read.xlsx(listfiles[7],sheetIndex = 1,header = FALSE)
file_photos = read.csv("C:/Users/adm/Downloads/photos.csv",sep=";")
#View(file_photos)
file_profiles = read.xlsx(listfiles[12],sheetIndex = 1,header = FALSE) ####
#View(file_profiles)
file_profiles3 = read.xlsx(listfiles[13],sheetIndex = 1,header = FALSE)###
#View(file_profiles)
file_statistics = read.csv("C:/Users/adm/Downloads/statistics.csv",sep=";")
#View(file_statistics)
file_videos = read.csv("C:/Users/adm/Downloads/videos.csv",sep=";")
#View(file_videos)
```

i need it merge to one dataset
simple way

```
n=merge(file_comments,file_groups,file_photos ,file_profiles,
      file_profiles3,file_statistics,

      file_videos, by ="owner_id")
```

but it returns me error

```
Error in fix.by (by.x, x): 'by' must define one or more columns as numbers, names or logical data
```

this
[Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid columnmergedata <- merge (dataset1, dataset2, by.x="personalid")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954874/error-in-fix-byby-x-x-by-must-specify-a-uniquely-valid-columnmergedata)
and this
[Merging data - Error in fix.by(by.x, x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038887/merging-data-error-in-fix-byby-x-x)
is not help me. And i don't know why.

owner_id is numeric

example

```
258894746

3389571
3389572
3389573
3389574
118850
```

What's wrong?
i need join all files at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge` does not accept more than two dataframes. You should apply it recursively with `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce` function [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

## Base R

```r
 Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "owner_id"),
           list(file_comments,file_groups,file_photos ,file_profiles,
                file_profiles3,file_statistics,
                file_videos)
        )
```

## `tidyverse` syntax

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list(file_comments,file_groups,file_photos ,file_profiles,
      file_profiles3,file_statistics,
      file_videos) %>% reduce(inner_join, by = "owner_id")
```

By the way, if you prefer left join rather than inner join (the one you intended to use):

- add `all.x = TRUE` argument in `merge`
- use `left_join` rather than `inner_join` in tidyverse solution